# MS Access: Prevent validation of subform

Tags: validation, ms-access, vba, subform

I am struggling with inadvertent triggering of validation rules when activating a subform.

In MS Access, I have a form with data about a patient, which contains a subform with one record of a medical device that belongs to this patient. The patients table has an [ID] field, and the medical devices table has a [PatientID] field. The medical devices table has a one-to-many relation with the patients table (one patient can have many medical devices).

When the form containing the subform is opened, the subform's `Form_Load()` method fills in certain fields such as the current date.

The problem is: As soon as any control of the subform is activated (via tabbing or clicking), the medical devices table's validation rules are triggered -- once and only once. After dismissing the validation error message, I can switch between the controls on the parent form and the subform without problem.

When I remove the code from the `Form_Load()` method, I can activate the subform's controls without triggering validation.

Both the parent form and the subform are linked to tables, not queries.

How can I fill in data in the subform using VBA without triggering validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use default values, not actual text. Default values only become "real" when some other field is completed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! For future reference: It is not possible to use user-defined functions for a table field's default value; but it is possible to use a user-defined VBA function for the default value of a form, so this is what I ended up doing.